# node.js util.inherits vs new

Tags: node.js

[On the Node.js documentation](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/util.html#util_util_inherits_constructor_superconstructor) we can see :

```
var util = require("util");
var events = require("events");

function MyStream() {
    events.EventEmitter.call(this);
}

util.inherits(MyStream, events.EventEmitter);

var stream = new MyStream();
```

Is it the same as :

```
function MyStream2() {
}
//MyStream2 = new events.EventEmitter; WRONG. Thank you @Esailija
MyStream2.prototype = new events.EventEmitter;

var stream2 = new MyStream2();
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If we edit your code to be working, that is:

```
MyStream2.prototype = new events.EventEmitter;
```

There will be still some differences:

- In your version, `MyStream2.prototype.constructor === events.EventEmitter`, with `inherits`, `MyStream2.prototype.constructor === MyStream2`
- Your version invokes `events.EventEmitter` constructor which could have side effects., whereas `inherits` uses `Object.create` which doesn't invoke the constructor function.
- Not related to the differences between chaining prototypes, but your version doesn't call parent constructor when the child constructor is called. So it should still have `function MyStream2() { events.EventEmitter.call(this); }` to properly establish initial state when the child constructor is called.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanations. I will learn about them.