# Adding an event listener to an object adds it too all its siblings

Tags: node.js, events

Adding an event to an object unexpectedly adds the same event to all of its siblings, i.e. objects created from the same constructor.

Here is a simple code to demonstrate this:

```js
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter

function Person() {
  EventEmitter.call(this)
}

Person.prototype = new EventEmitter()
Person.prototype.talk = function() {
  this.emit('talking')
}

var a = new Person()
var b = new Person()

a.on('talking', function() {
  console.log("a is talking")
})

a.talk()    // Prints "a is talking" (expected)
b.talk()    // Also prints "a is talking" ??? why ???
```

Why is this happening and how can I make each object maintain its own set of events?

Comment: What version of Node are you using? In v0.12.0 it seems to work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a problem with the approach you're using to inherit `EventEmitter`.

```
Person.prototype = new EventEmitter();
```

It invokes `events.EventEmitter` constructor which could have side effects. For example

```
console.log(Person.prototype.constructor === EventEmitter); // prints true
```

Consider using the following to inherit `Person` from `EventEmitter`.

```
var util = require('util');
util.inherits(Person, EventEmitter);
```

It uses `Object.create` which doesn't invoke the constructor function as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13673402/1520671)